# How to make sound output from Bluetooth instead of speakers in IOS 17

Tags: bluetooth, ios17, avaudiosessioncategory

my issue
https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_session/issues/120

When I set the AVAudioSessionCategory avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord， sound to come out of the built-in speaker instead of Bluetooth headphones。ios17 。It is normal in IOS 16 or 15

`final session = await AudioSession.instance; await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration( avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord, avAudioSessionCategoryOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2dp, avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.defaultMode, avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy: AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.defaultPolicy, avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.none, androidAudioAttributes: const AndroidAudioAttributes( contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.music, flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none, usage: AndroidAudioUsage.media, ), androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gain, androidWillPauseWhenDucked: true, ));`

How to make sound output from Bluetooth instead of speakers in IOS 17?

How to make sound output from Bluetooth instead of speakers in IOS 17?

Answer (score 0):

```
 [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode:AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording options:nil error:nil];
 
  AVAudioSessionPortDescription *builtInMicPort = nil;
  for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *portDescription in audioSession.availableInputs) {
      if ([portDescription.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic]) {
          builtInMicPort = portDescription;
          break;
      }
  }

  if (builtInMicPort) {
      NSError *inputError = nil;
      [audioSession setPreferredInput:builtInMicPort error:&inputError];

      if (inputError) {
          NSLog(@"inputError：%@", inputError);
      }else{
          NSLog(@"change success");
      }
  } else {
      NSLog(@"inputError");
  }
  [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

set mode AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording normall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).